# Query for Partial Object in Array - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a simple structured document like this:

```
"people" : [
    {
        "id" : "6241863",
        "amount" : 5
    }
],
```

People can contain more than one element. I've managed to get this to work:

```
db.village.findOne({"people": {"$in": [{"id": "6241863", "amount": 5}]}})
```

But I want to ignore amount and search for any document containing people with id 6241863 and any amount.

Comment: you can't retrieve part of array of single document in find query. you must do it in  client side

Comment: dude how did u save the data like that , i have a shema like this product_video:[{thum_src:String,video_name:String,video_path:String}] and i dont know how to save the data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [advanced query documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray), you can mix array value queries with [dot notation for reaching into objects](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29). Here's an example using your schema:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.0
connecting to: test
> db.users.save({_id: 1, friends: [{id: 2, name: 'bob'}]})
> db.users.find({friends: {id: 2, name: 'bob'}})
{ "_id" : 1, "friends" : [ { "id" : 2, "name" : "bob" } ] }

> db.users.find({'friends.id': 2})
{ "_id" : 1, "friends" : [ { "id" : 2, "name" : "bob" } ] }

> db.users.find({'friends.name': 'bob'})
{ "_id" : 1, "friends" : [ { "id" : 2, "name" : "bob" } ] }

> db.users.find({'friends.name': 'ted'})
>
```

Comment: How would you go about doing this if there was an object above users, such as `roles` that contained `users` and `admins`, and you still wanted to search just users?

Answer (score 0):

Try with that

```
db.village.findOne({"people" : { "$in" : [{ "id" : "6241863" , "amount" : { "$ne" : null } }]}})
```